# Etymology of ずっこけ

Tags: etymology

Where does ずっこけ come from? It doesn't have kanji, but it also isn't repetitive like onomatopoeia-so does it just not use the kanji anymore, or does it have strange roots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to be a combination of `ずる` (old form of `ずれる` - to slip/slide down) and `転ける【こける】` (to fall down / fail).